# Convert SpMatrix to Matrix

Tags: haskell, matrix, vector, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to find a shorter, or more efficient way, of converting a `SpMatrix` (from `Data.Sparse.SpMatrix`) to `Matrix` (from `Data.Matrix`).
Using the built in functions I managed to convert them in the order `SpMatrix Double` to `[(IxRow, IxCol, Double)]` to `[Double]` to `Matrix Double`.
I wonder if it possible to skip any of these middle steps.

Small example:

```
Import Data.Sparse.Common
Import qualified Data.Matrix as M

main :: IO ()
main = do
   let a = mkDiagonal 3 [1,2,3] :: SpMatrix Double
       b = toDenseListSM a
       c = map (\(_, _, x) -> x) b
       d = M.fromList 3 3 c
   print d
```

Output (`d`):

```
1.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 2.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 3.0
```

So, in the above example, I'm looking for a way to skip steps `b` and `c`.

Comment: Just use a `matrix` builder.

Answer (score 1):

If `Data.Matrix` is from the `matrix` package and `Data.Sparse.SpMatrix` is from the `sparse-linear-algebra` package, then you ought to be able to do something like this (untested):

```
convert :: Num a => SpMatrix a -> Matrix a
convert sp = matrix (nrows sp) (ncols sp) (lookupWD_SM sp)
```

Here `matrix` is from `Data.Matrix` and `nrows`, `ncols`, and `lookupWD_SM` are from `Data.Sparse.SpMatrix`.

Comment: It compiles but output isn't as expected. The diagonal becomes 2.0, 3.0, 0.0 (instead of expected 1.0, 2.0, 3.0). Rest are 0.
Yes, your assumption about packages were correct.

Comment: @Pompan Probably one or the other package uses 1-indexing instead of 0-indexing. I trust you to be able to work out which, and what to do about it.